# Correct way to write these sentences? Which or that?

Tags: that

Should I use "which" or "that" in these sentences. I appreciate they are virtually the same sentence. I don't think it makes a difference here but I speak/write British English (not American English).

1. The twin room has its own ensuite that/which is equipped with a shower.
2. This stylish room has its own ensuite which/that is equipped with a shower.

Thanks

Comment: You can use either, but a tighter construction would omit the _that/which is_.

Comment: A good reference is http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001461.html

Answer (score 0):

1. The twin room has its own ensuite, which is equipped with a shower.
2. The twin room has its own ensuite that is equipped with a shower.

These sentences are not the same. The first sentence tells us that there is only one twin room, and it is equipped with a shower. The clause which is equipped gives us additional information, but it doesn’t change the meaning of the sentence. Remove the clause and the info would still be clear: The twin room has its own ensuite with a shower.

The second sentence suggests that we have multiple twin room, all ensuite with shower.

But on the other sentence,
This stylish room has its own ensuite which is equipped with a shower.

Comment: Please comment on your additional use of the comma in the first instance.

Comment: @user292594 your interpretation of the second sentence is not right.  Where is the suggestion that there is more than one twin room?  Maybe you are thinking of these two examples: "The room which has a shower is [somewhere] " versus "the room, which has a shower, is [somewhere]" in which the meanings are distinct in a somewhat similar way to that which you are suggesting.